# How to hyperlink to same cell in a different worksheet?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've searched for this, and found several questions, but never with the same criteria. I'm on Excel 2021/Windows.

I want to create hyperlinks in sheet A that go to the same cell (as the current cell, i.e. the cell the formula is in) in sheet B, without hardcoding the cell addresses.

IOW, in SheetA!L28, I could create a formula `=HYPERLINK([workbook.xlsx]SheetB!L28`; that goes to the same cell, but it hardcodes the cell address.

Is it possible to create the formula so that it substitutes the current cell address? I've tried various ways of substituting ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()) into the place for the cell address, but so far without success.

Comment: You may need to use [`INDIRECT`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/indirect-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't like using INDIRECT() due to it's being volatile...

With a Sheet1 and Sheet2 this seems to work as a valid formula on Sheet1

```
=HYPERLINK("#"&ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN(),,,"Sheet2"),"Go to this cell on Sheet2")
```

Comment: Perfect (and I didn't know how to do it with INDIRECT anyway :)! I definitely would have never gotten there on my own.